# No module named mftracker

Tags: python, module

I don't understand why, but I installed all the requirements, opencv, simpleCV, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, openTLD, but I can't run this program:

```
from mftracker import *
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("inputcar.avi")
_, img = cap.read()
_, img = cap.read()

bb = [74, 90, 30, 40]
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

mftrack("inputcar.avi", bb)
```

When I run it, it show me only the picture from the video and this:

```
Running: C:\pyOpenTLD-master\video\Se__car.py (Mon Feb 23 17:20:48 2015)


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\pyOpenTLD-master\video\Se__car.py", line 1, in <module>

    from mftracker import *

ImportError: No module named mftracker
```

Comment: but did you install https://github.com/jayrambhia/MFTracker

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `mftracker` itself. Since you're running on Windows, a good source for Python packages is usually [Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) but unfortunately `mftracker` is not listed there. It is also not available on PyPi so `pip install` will not work.

As @robert_x44 noted in the comment, the package *is* available [on github](https://github.com/jayrambhia/MFTracker). A `.zip` file is available and the package is Python-only, so assuming you have `pip` installed you can do:

```
pip install https://github.com/jayrambhia/MFTracker/archive/master.zip
```

...and it should install the package for you.

Comment: Thanks @mfitsp & @robert_x44!! it works, i didn´t see that package, i was searching in google, but whit out success. 
Thanks a lot guys

Sorry if i misspelled English